# Android activity hangs due to airpush and startapp sdks

Tags: android

I implement airpush and startapp ads sdks in my android game.it works perfect when net is availible on my mob game uns fluently but when net is not available my game hangs due to startapp sdk or may b airpush.it throws some exceptions in my logcat below is the error due to which activity hangs without net please help me out how to deal with this.Thanks

error : 
unable to handle GetHtmlAdService command!!!
com.startapp.android.publish.c.e: Error execute exception host is unnresolded: www.startappexchange.com:80
com.startapp.android.publish.c.d.a(unknown resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem running both of the SDK's together. I suggest you contact Startapp's support and I am sure they can assist you- support@startapp.com.

Or visit their website at www.startapp.com